# Single post pagination

Tags: posts, pagination, title, nextpage

I have used `<!--nextpage-->` tag to paginate longer individual posts, These longer single posts have structure as Title, Content, A, B, C, By using above said tag, I want to paginate A, B, C content only and show title, content on all the paginated pages. How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a few minutes and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to modify the *content pagination* with the `content_pagination` filter.

Here's a way to always display the content of the first page:

```
/**
 * Content Pagination: Always display the content of the first page
 */
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    // Nothing to do if there's no pagination
    if( count( $pages ) <= 1 )
        return $pages;

    // Get the first page and remove it from the pages array
    $firstpage = array_shift( $pages );

    // Prepend the first page to all other pages
    foreach( $pages as &$page )
        $page = $firstpage . $page;

    // Add the first page again
    array_unshift( $pages, $firstpage );

    return $pages;
} );
```

### Example:

Let's assume the content pagination is defined as:

```
aaa
<!--nextpage-->
bbb
<!--nextpage-->
ccc
```

Then the *first* page is:

```
aaa
```

The *second* one becomes:

```
aaa
bbb
```

and the *third* one displays as:

```
aaa
ccc
```

### Update:

To have the first page as:

```
aaa
bbb
```

the second one as:

```
aaa
ccc
```

etc, then we only need to comment out this line:

```
// Add the first page again
array_unshift( $pages, $firstpage );
```

Comment: But i have aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd and i want to  show aaa, bbb on first page and aaa ccc, aaa ddd on next pages.

Comment: You only need to remove a single line of code from the snippet, can you see which one? @PARVINDER

Comment: Can u explain @birgire

Comment: Please check out the updated answer @PARVINDER

Comment: Any progress on the problem? @PARVINDER